# Конвертация даты C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Получаю с сервера данные, дата имеет такой формат: `2018-03-15T00:00:00+03:00`.

Вытягиваю дату из ответа:

```
Date = Convert.ToDateTime(GetValue(task, "Date"))
```

И на выходе получаю дату **03/14/2018** (на 3 часа меньше, чем есть). Пробовал использовать разные культуры, добавлять `ToUniversalTime`/`ToLocalTime`, но все равно на выходе не та дата.

Как правильно конвертировать дату, чтоб она была в нужном формате?

Comment: В ответе приходит часовой пояс: +03:00. Вы его учитываете?

Comment: @EvUd, мне он не нужен. Но, как я понял, он учитывается при конвертации и дата получается на 3 часа меньше.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хотите оперировать датой с нужным часовым поясом, то лучше используйте более подходящий для этого тип [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var date = "2018-03-15T00:00:00+03:00";
var dateOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(date);
```

Comment: Использую `Convert.ToDateTime`, потому что конвертирую из `object`.

Comment: @Nikita никто не мешает уточнить тип `(string) GetValue(task, "Date")` при условии, что истинный тип строка, конечно.

Comment: Спасибо, `DateTimeOffset` именно то, что мне нужно. Так же нашел еще одно решение: `Convert.ToDateTime(GetValue(task, "Date"), CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture)`

Comment: Можно ещё добавить, что я бы не рекомендовал забивать на часовой пояс. Если сервис в другом часовом поясе по отношению к клиенту, то думаю, что он тоже ожидает получить дату со смещением